# Link button control using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have set of link buttons in my masterpage and one button in my content page.
i want when i click the any one of link button in the masterpage the value in the content page will change. How i can do this. Can any one able to help me because i am new in asp.net 
Thank you

Comment: Check out this link it may help you solve your problem as well as teach you what you can do with the master page to the content panel: http://odetocode.com/code/450.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do something like this from your master page

```
var linkButton = ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("contentPageButton1") as LinkButton;
linkButton.Text = "Foo";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set it up with events.
In your master page:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> SomethingChanged;
```

In your content page:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
   base.OnInit(e);
   ((MyMasterPage)Page.Master).SomethingChanged += (s, ev) => UpdateStuff();
}
```